# ActiveModel::Serializer instance variable in class unaccessible in method

Tags: ruby

I have the snippet below in my `ActiveModel::Serializer`.  It's a recursive method, but I need to add to an array that's returned when the recursion ends.

So, I set an instance variable `@rows` equal to an empty array `[]`.  I push onto that array in the method, but Ruby is returning an `undefined method 'push' for nil:NilClass`.

```
class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :hierarchies

  @rows = []

  def hierarchies_run(child, user)
    hierarchy = UserHierarchy.where(child: child, user_id: user).first

    if hierarchy
      @rows.push(UserSimpleSerializer.new(User.find(hierarchy.child), :root => false))
      hierarchies_run(hierarchy.parent, current.id)
    else
      @rows.push(UserSimpleSerializer.new(User.find(child), :root => false))
    end
  end

  def hierarchies
    hierarchies_run(current.id, current.id)
    @rows
  end
end
```

Why is it returning this error?

Comment: Please show all of your code

Comment: This is all of the code but wrapped inside of a `class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`

Comment: Right, your update explains the problem, which is why I asked for more code. You're defining `@rows` in the class scope and not the instance scope, since instance variables default to `nil`, `@rows` will be `nil` in any instance methods. You should define it in a constructor

Comment: Got it, put it in an answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have defined `@row` in your class (the constructor itself) instead of the instance. You should put the initialization of `@row` into something like:

```
class MySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :hierarchies

  def initialize(*args)
    super
    @rows = []
  end

  ...
```

Then when you call

```
  MySerializer.new
```

`@row` will be initialized within the instance's context

Comment: (Wouldn't you need a call to super?)

Comment: @DaveNewton I think you are right. I will update my answer.

Comment: In 0.10.7 you need to do `def initialize(*args)`

Comment: @littleforest thanks, you are definitely right since this is about extending the ActiveModel::Serializer. It is always safer that way. I will update my answer.